# jQuery: animate scroll to next only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jQuery function whereby clicking on each instance of `.load-more` will fade in the next instance of `.inside` and scroll to it. The first `.load-more` click works fine, scrolls you down to `.inside` successfully, but then clicking on the next `.load-more` fades in the next instance of `.inside` but is for some reason not scrolling to it, not too sure why?

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/K9nMS/5/ 
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var divs = $(".wrap > .div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
        divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='inside'><div class='new'></div></div>");
    }

});


$(document).ready(function () {

    Resize();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    Resize();
});

function Resize() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height() + 'px';
    $('.inside').css('height', windowHeight);
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".new .div:last-child").after("<span class='load-more'>More?</span>");
    $('.inside').hide().filter(":first-child").show();

    $('.load-more').click(function () {
        var nextinside = $(this).parent().parent('.inside').nextAll(".inside:first"),
            nextloadmore = $(this).nextAll(".load-more:first");
        $(this).hide();
        nextinside.fadeIn();
        nextloadmore.fadeIn();
        $('.wrap').animate({
            scrollTop: nextinside.offset().top - 0
        }, 700);
    });
});
```

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have three document.ready() functions? You should put all of that code inside one singular function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the position for scrolltop for each successive set as a multiple of the set index:

```
scrollTop: nextinside.index() * nextinside.offset().top
```

I have it working for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/K9nMS/7/